# How do I make a Area2D duplicate when entered (C#)

Tags: c#, duplicates, game-engine, game-development, godot

I want to make it so whenever a body enters an area, it duplicates itself. The original one deletes itself while the duplicate is there. and I want it so whenever a body enters that duplicate, it duplicates itself while its duplicate is there, and I want it so whenever a body enters that duplicates duplicate, it duplicates itself while its duplicate is there, and so on and so on. How do I do this? I know how to detect collision already. but I don't know how to create duplicates.

I tried to somehow look up gdscript code for it, and translate it onto c#, but I have no idea how to.

Comment: Do you mean the body duplicates itself when it enters an area? Or do you mean the area duplicates itself when a body enters it?

Comment: The area duplicates itself when its entered. And I want the duplicates to be duplicated when entered as well.

Comment: The answer to this will depend on how you're detecting the collision and how you have set up your scene.  You will need to provide more information e.g. the code currently handling collisions and the scene tree.  It is also expected that you will provide an explanation of the ways you've already tried to solve this problem.

Comment: I used signals to detect collisions. Everything is stored inside a single scene. Like I have said I found GDScript code and tried to make it in C#, but I couldn't. I'm new to godot so I don't know much about it yet.

Comment: When you say "duplicates"? What, specifically, do you mean? For example, if an area is named "BlahArea" of type Area2D, do you: 1. want a brand new BlahArea created as a sibling and given a new name such as BlahArea2? 2. want a copy of BlahArea and it's current values created and given a new name such as BlahArea2? or 3. want the current BlahArea reset to the state one would expect it to have when it is newly created? If you have working gdscript code, you might add it to your question.

Comment: my Area2D area is a coin, and one coin at a screen would be boring. i want to duplicate it at a given rate, so theres always more than one coin. To do that i want the duplicate to be similar to the original area, just with different coordinates. so i think thats the first one